# Why does my TCP application misses some packets when sent rapidly

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a multiple clients per server application in C# using async sockets. Each client on connection sends 10 items. The problem is, when starting lots of clients quickly, it appears that each client sent less than the 10 items and sometimes it sends nothing, the server just logs them connecting only.

The packet structure is the first 4 bytes are an int with size of data in them. Here's a part of server code. Each connected client has its own receive buffer which BeginReceive should write to.

```
private void Recieve(IAsyncResult iar) //Called when socket receives something.
{
    Socket server_conn = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;

    if (!SocketConnected(server_conn))
    {
        server_conn.Close();
        logthis("Client Disconnected");
        return;
    }
    int n = server_conn.EndReceive(iar);  //Stop Receiving and parse data, n is number of bytes received

    ClientData asdf = null;
    foreach (ClientData cls in clientlist)
    {
        if (server_conn.RemoteEndPoint == cls.clientsock.RemoteEndPoint) //Who sent this data
        {
            asdf = cls; //cls is who sent this data

            //Start a new thread and pass received bytes to it in order to be parsed
            var t = new Thread(() => parse(cls, n,cls.recvbuffer));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            break;
        }
    }

    asdf.recvbuffer = new byte[1024];      //Clear buffer of client
    server_conn.BeginReceive(asdf.recvbuffer, 0, asdf.recvbuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Recieve), server_conn); //Start receiving again

}

private void parse(ClientData theclient, int nobytesreceived, byte[] bytesreceived)
{
    ClientData cls = theclient;
    int n = nobytesreceived;
    byte[] receivedbytes = bytesreceived;


    lock(s)
    {
    if (!cls.dataphase)  //If there's no fragmented packets still waiting to be read
    {
        cls.dataphase = true;   
        byte[] sizeinbytes = new byte[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            sizeinbytes[i] = receivedbytes[i];
        }
        int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeinbytes, 0);  //Read first four bytes of packet to get size of data

        if ((n - 4) == size)  //If received number of bytes - 4 is equals to datasize
        {
            byte[] payload = new byte[size];
            Array.Copy(receivedbytes, 4, payload, 0, (n - 4)); //Copy data to separately to payload array to be displayed to user
            logthis(cls.clientsock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            logthis(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payload));
            cls.dataphase = false;       //packet read successfully 
        }
        else if ((n - 4) < size) //If received amount of bytes is less than data size (fragmented data)
        {
            cls.data = new byte[size];
            for (int i = 4; i <= n - 4; i++)
            {
                cls.data[i - 4] += receivedbytes[i];
            }

            cls.datasize = size; //And cls.dataphase will remain true so it can be handled correctly the next time we receive something from same client
        }
        else if((n-4) > size)  //If received amount of bytes is bigger than data (lumped packets)
        {
            byte[] payload = new byte[size];
            byte[] otherpacket = new byte[(n - 4) - size];

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                payload[i] += receivedbytes[i + 4];

            }

            logthis(cls.clientsock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            logthis(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payload));
            Array.Copy(receivedbytes, (size + 4), otherpacket, 0, ((n - 4) - size));
            receivedbytes = new byte[(n - 4) - size];
            receivedbytes = otherpacket;
            cls.dataphase = false;
            parse(cls, ((n - 4) - size), receivedbytes); //Send rest of packet to read again
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //not implemented, supposed to handle fragmented packets
        if (n >= cls.datasize)
        {

        }
        else if (n < cls.datasize)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You have a pretty bad race condition there. if `asdf.recvbuffer = new byte[1024];` happens before `parse(cls, n,cls.recvbuffer)` you are going to be sending a empty buffer to `parse`.

Comment: Yea I noticed this when I was revising my code just now, I now copy recvbuffer to another byte array before calling and pass it to parse(). Now I only get the first 10 items from the first client connected and nothing at all from the other clients :/

Comment: The code is far too much. I will not take the time to comprehend it.

Comment: I could have used FIFO ques for buffers and it would have made the the code a lot more simpler and easier to read but it's too late now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from

```
else
{
    //not implemented, supposed to handle fragmented packets
```

I would put money on the fact that you are hitting that else statement and loosing data. As soon as you don't have a complete read of a packet or two packets lumped together returned from your read function (which is a lot more common than you think) your client is now stuck in `cls.dataphase = true;` and will never get out of it.

Comment: +1 and note that there are no packets, let alone fragmented packets, in the application. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. Either you got enough bytes for your current purpose or you didn't.

Comment: @Ejp Yea, I didn't want to confuse the OP, but you are absolutely correct. He was using the term "Packet" where the term "Message" would be much more appropriate, I was just trying to use the same terminology.

Comment: I'll try implementing that part and see if it fixes it. I didn't bet the problem might come from it because each item has a really small size and they're always just put together in a single message/packet. (each 24 bytes and 240bytes total)

Comment: If the messages are small you may be getting 2 or 3 messages in a single `Read` call. So you are hitting your `else if((n-4) > size)` a few times as it processes each message then the last message hits the `else if ((n - 4) < size)` block if it was not fully read and now your client can no longer send data. From your comment "*Now I only get the first 10 items from the first client connected and nothing at all from the other clients*" You are likely getting 10 1/2 messages worth and it processes the first 10 and fails on the 11th.

Comment: Size is calculated every time parse is entered. The problem will come up if last message is less than 4 bytes long and leads to calculating wrong size. It's another bug I need to handle. Thanks.

Comment: The term 'message' is no more appropriate than 'packet'. Neither of them exists at the level of a TCP application. Just a byte-stream.

Comment: @EJP I was not talking about the TCP bytestream, I was talking about the protocol running on top of the TCP bytestream which appears to be a 4 byte length prefix followed by a payload per message.